# Python Pip cannot recognize any module using pip command

Tags: python, windows, pip

When I use `pip install camelcase`, it successfully installs the package and when I run pip freeze I am able to see this package installed on the terminal.

```
from camelcase import CamelCase
```

It produces an error where No module named camelcase when I use it on my file. Same error for other packages such as requests etc

However, it works perfectly fine when I do

```
python3 -m pip install camelcase
```

I have the following to my environmental user variable path for Windows

```
C:\Python38
C:\Python38\Scripts
```

Python version I am using is Python 3.8.2 and the pip version is 20.3.3

Kindly advise. Thank you

Comment: try reinstalling pip by `python -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip`

Comment: You must reinstall or update your Python version